# Laravel Excel with Microsoft Excel Macro Buttons

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-excel

I Use Laravel php Framework and laravel-excel plugin For edit pre created Microsoft Macro Excel file.this process worked charm but after edit existing macro sheet buttons not display.how to solve my problem? 
I attached My Requirement and Result as a Picture.
Buttons with Macro File : [image] 
output File : [image] 
I use, 
Laravel 5.54
Laravel-Excel 2.1
Php 7.3.2
with Xampp Server

```
        return Excel::load('Salary Bank File.xlsm', function($excel) use ($data) {
            $excel->sheet('com_upload ', function($sheet)  use ($data)
            {

                foreach ($data as $data) {
                $sheet->appendRow($data);
                }
           }); 
        })->download('xlsm');
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: @sachinAghera thank for your reply.i want to get macro buttons to my output file.i input excel with macro buttons.but output isnt show buttons.

Comment: Sheet::macro('setOrientation', function (Sheet $sheet, $orientation) {
    $sheet->getDelegate()->getPageSetup()->setOrientation($orientation);
});

Comment: @SachinAghera thank for your reply where shoud i place this code? can you give a answer with code exsample?